# Suggest another way for accesing win32_processor

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

the following code is used to access the Win32 processor information....
is there is any other way for getting the win32 processor information (like using different classes). here i have used the class `WqlObjectQuery` and `ManagementObjectSearcher`.

```
WqlObjectQuery wquery = new WqlObjectQuery("select * from Win32_Processor");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wquery);
        foreach (ManagementObject mo1 in searcher1.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mo1.ToString());
        }
```

can we use any other classes to get the properties of win32 processor

Comment: All depends on what information you need. I'm not used to getting this information but some basic information can be obtained through environment variables or the registry.

Comment: WMI can do the same thing is this .NET 4.5 specific or are you wanting to do this for .NET 3.5 ?

Comment: @Nick: Thanks Nick, actually my doubt is, can we use managementclass to use the query "Select * from win32_processor".

Comment: @DJ: Am using .net 3.5 framework.

Comment: is it possible to get the hardware and software information using wmi..?

Comment: There are a lot of things you can get using WMI I will post a few examples that work for you to use in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks DJ, i am new to WMI, your examples will surely help me

Comment: I have used it for many years and you can play around with the few code examples I have shown you.. it's a really useful thing to use. I hope this helps

Comment: yes it is definitely possible to get the hardware as well as software using WMI...there is a tool provided by microsoft to navigate the WMI classes and functions. The tool is Windows management Instrumentation tester. it can be opened by typing wbemtest in command prompt. You can experiment using the tool. Moreover you can check this Link and this link, and trying doing some research from your side.

Comment: @Vikram: thanks for your information, i will try to use it. but i want to do it using .net code(c#).and your link is not visible now

Comment: all the links that I posted work not sure if you have issues reaching US links because I am not sure where you are located .. all of the code examples I have provided are in C# and prior to posting the code I have tested it personally so I know it works..

Comment: @Dj: please see this code:                                                                                            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery("Win32_LogicalDisk"));
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(mo["version"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(mo["csname"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(mo["manufacturer"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(mo["windowsdiscovery"].ToString());
        }

Comment: i got the exception at the line of getting version number.

Comment: hold on one sec.. I am answering a question for another OP give me 5 mins ok

Comment: I fiound the error, i entered win32_logicaldisk instead of win32_processor. still am getting management exception error in csname line.

Comment: look at the first example to get the mo["Name"] I would recommend downloading the WMI Tool so that you know based on what ever query that you are running you will know which properties to get I hope this makes sense..

Comment: get the tool here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en it will help you in regards to understanding what you can do with WMI Query

Comment: Thanks DJ. I am downloading that tool. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Get the Current Processor name running on the Machine

Checkout the WMI Explorer as well it's a really good tool to use [WMI Query Tool](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/build-queries-and-explore-the-windows-wmi-database-with-wmi-explorer/5007)

[MSDN WMI Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[WMI Query Language](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46390/WMI-Query-Language-by-Example)

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"]);
}
```

//Get Name , Manufacturer, Computer Name, etc...

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mosQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection1 = mosQuery.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject manObject in queryCollection1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name : " + manObject["name"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Version : " + manObject["version"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer : " + manObject["Manufacturer"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Computer Name : " + manObject["csname"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Windows Directory : " + manObject["WindowsDirectory"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: DJ, i tried your code it makes an exception at run time, can you tell me why that happend...? it shows management exception.

Comment: which code / line caused the exception I get zero errors can you show me the code that you are using..? thanks

Comment: ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery("Win32_LogicalDisk"));
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(mo["version"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(mo["csname"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(mo["manufacturer"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(mo["windowsdiscovery"].ToString());
        }

Comment: @Gomathipriya you're getting an exception because the [Win32_LogicalDisk object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) has no "version" property.  Or csname, manufacturer, or windowsdiscovery for that matter.  Always check if a property is null before using it.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is definitely possible to get the hardware as well as software using WMI...there is a tool provided by microsoft to navigate the WMI classes and functions. The tool is Windows management Instrumentation tester. it can be opened by typing wbemtest in command prompt. You can experiment using the tool. Moreover you can check this [Link](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2010/02/18/collecting-hardware-information-using-c-and-wmi/) and this [link](http://www.ithastobecool.com/2009/12/18/wbemtest-handy-tool-for-testing-your-wmi-queries/), and trying doing some research from your side.

Apart from all this you can use the query as "select * from Win32_Processor where DeviceID=CPU0" as you want to get the information about single processor

Comment: This is a comment not an answer Vikram it's probably best to show coded examples vs just posting links.

Comment: @DJKRAZE : sure will it into comments section. Thanks :)