# How to get CPU brand information in ARM64?

Tags: c, windows, intrinsics, arm64

In Windows X86, the CPU brand can be queried with `cpuid` intrinsic function.
Here is a sample of the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

int main(void)
{
    int cpubrand[4 * 3];

    __cpuid(&cpubrand[0], 0x80000002);
    __cpuid(&cpubrand[4], 0x80000003);
    __cpuid(&cpubrand[8], 0x80000004);

    char str[48];
    memset(str, 0, sizeof str);
    memcpy(str, cpubrand, sizeof cpubrand);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

What is the alternative of this in Windows ARM64?

Answer (score 8):

The direct way to get this information would be to read the *Main ID Register* `MIDR_EL1`. This could be done via the `mrs` instruction in (inline) assembly or via the `_ReadStatusReg` instrinct.

Unfortunately this register cannot be accessed from user mode (i.e. `EL0`) and every attempt throws an exception. At Linux the behavior is then emulated so that `MIDR_EL1` can still be accessed. However, I do not know or have the opportunity to test whether Windows also offers this feature.

---

References:

- [ARM64 CPU Feature Registers at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arm64/cpu-feature-registers.html) (how Linux made `MIDR_EL1` accessible)
- [Main ID Register at developer.arm.com](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0500/d/system-control/aarch64-register-descriptions/main-id-register--el1?lang=en) (from the Cortex-A53 docs)
- [ARM64 Instrincts at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/arm64-intrinsics?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 5):

Although probably *not* the answer you're looking for (i.e. directly interrogating the CPU), you can fetch the "ProcessorNameString" value from the Windows Registry using code like the following:

```c
#define BUFSIZ 64 // For easy adjustment of limits, if required

char answer[BUFSIZ] = "Error Reading CPU Name from Registry!", inBuffer[BUFSIZ] = "";
const char *csName = "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0";
HKEY hKey;  DWORD gotType, gotSize = BUFSIZ;
if (RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, csName, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    if (!RegQueryValueExA(hKey, "ProcessorNameString", nullptr, &gotType, (PBYTE)(inBuffer), &gotSize)) {
        if ((gotType == REG_SZ) && strlen(inBuffer)) strcpy(answer, inBuffer);
    }
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

This will (or *should*) give you the processor's 'name' that the Windows system sees! I don't have access to an `ARM64` system, so I can't properly test it but, on my `x64` system, I get the following (correct) string: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz` (which is *exactly* that returned by using `__cpuid()` calls to get the "Brand String").

However, like you, I would be very interested to know of a way to do this *directly* - i.e., how would the Windows O/S get this info on an `ARM64` system?

Comment: the name in CPUID instruction is a 48-byte null-terminated string, so you don't actually need such a huge buffer

Comment: @phuclv A very good point (see edit - also made code a bit cleaner). I transferred the code from part of a project that was using a similar registry entry, but which had potentially much longer strings. (I've used 64 chars, because I'm not sure the ARM64 system - if there even is one - conforms to the Intel standard.)

Comment: Just for the information, standard Task Manager on Win10 uses this method to get CPU name.

Comment: @ge0rdi But the question still remains: How does Windows *initially* determine that info, so that it can be written to the registry? I suspect it's probably reading stuff from the BIOS (during installation).

Comment: "is a 48-byte null-terminated string, so you don't actually need such a huge buffer " ... famous last words.

Answer (score 2):

Not a way to get name directly from the CPU either, but you can get processor name from the WMI [Win32_Processor class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor)

It can be obtained by running `wmic cpu get name` in cmd or `(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).Name` in PowerShell. [Getting it from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14602301/995714) is also easy, something like

```cs
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Processor")
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(mo["Name"]);
}
```

However [doing that from C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer) is a lot trickier. Luckily there's already a similar example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431517/995714). The main part should be like this

```
BSTR query    = SysAllocString(L"SELECT Name FROM Win32_Processor");
hr = services->lpVtbl->ExecQuery(services, language, query, WBEM_FLAG_BIDIRECTIONAL, NULL, &results);
...
hr = result->lpVtbl->Get(result, L"Name", 0, &name, 0, 0);
SysFreeString(query);
```

Comment: Using System.Management failed for me on a Surface Pro X. It threw an unexpected PlatformNotSupported exception citing the arm architecture.

Comment: @DanielHenry can you try [`CIM_Processor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-processor)? WMI has been deprecated and moved to CIM which is more platform independent

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use [cpuinfo](https://github.com/pytorch/cpuinfo) which is a cross-platform CPU information library and also [supports ARM64](https://github.com/pytorch/cpuinfo/issues/30)

```
cpuinfo_initialize();
printf("Running on %s CPU\n", cpuinfo_get_package(0)->name);
```

It seems it also gets the CPU name [from the registry key `HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0`](https://github.com/pytorch/cpuinfo/blob/47727656bd89a8243fc4aa25eec34732c0394a75/src/arm/windows/init.c#L190) like [Windows Task Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588765/how-to-get-cpu-brand-information-in-arm64#comment110514516_60589197)